# Performance issue with setTextColor()

Tags: android, performance, textview

I made an activity which uses `xml` layout definition and a programmatically implemented part. That *programmatically implemented part* frequently calls `setTextColor(color)` of one of the `TextView`s and causes lots of unneeded methods like onMeasuer(). It changes only color, but it takes too much CPU time.

Because of 25 calls a second it takes 40% of overall CPU time. How do to avoid that performance subsidence?

Comment: Why are you changing the text's color 25 times a second?

Comment: I display the change of game score using "fading" effect.